# What is the word for your state when something is not how you expected it to be, in an unpleasant way?

Tags: word-request

I’m looking for a word that describes your state when something is not how you expected it to be. Not in a pleasant way but the opposite.

Is baffled appropriate? But I think baffled doesn’t really show any emotion but just a sense of confusion. Also baffled expresses in a large quantity. I want something of less magnitude.

I don’t want to express something mysterious. It's like I expected something and I got it. But with something else that I don’t like. If that makes any sense.

I want to use it in a sentence like this one:

> The overall experience was a pleasant one, don’t get me wrong. But a few things _________ me and made me wonder if it's the harsh truth.

Comment: _Baffled_ does not imply excitement, but it _does_ imply puzzlement.

Comment: @KateBunting Ok. I get it. But still, it has a neutral tone to it. I want a little... umm... disappointing tone

Comment: There's a whole bunch of words for this. Try _discombobulated_ is you want to sound fancy. Basically you want to say _... upset me and..._ Another word is _disconcert._

Comment: Ahh... That's it. Discombobulated. That's the word I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll make an answer myself. That's what you gotta do if you find the answer, isn’t it?

Comment: "But I had a few misgivings..." (There were a few issues that made the experience not entirely a positive one.)

Comment: @KateBunting that's a new way I learned today. Thanks. I’ll add this as the second answer. Or you can do it.

Comment: You should wait for someone to post an answer (you can ask them to change a comment to an answer) and then indicate that you have accepted it.

Comment: Oh ok.... I’ll delete them then.

Comment: @User40475 _Discombobulate_ is a jokey word rather than a 'fancy' one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest "I had a few misgivings about it". This doesn't imply that you were puzzled or confused, just that the experience was not entirely a positive one.

Comment: Thanks :). About _discombobulated_, is it used in a comical sense?

Comment: @Apoorv, I would say so.